# VBA excel: Import tables from MS Word within a certain selection

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble with importing tables from an MS Word document to Excel. For background, the word documents are all formatted the same way, with tables for signals under "input" another section with a tables for signals under "output" headings.

I'd like to be able to import the tables and split them between sheets based on if they under the input heading, or output heading. Setup in the MSWord doc is like so

1.1.1 Inputs

[tables]

1.1.2 Outputs

[tables]

1.1.3 Blah de Blah

So far I have it importing all tables that reference signals with the below code, but that's about as far as I've been able to take it. Can anyone help me out, is it even possible to import from a selection?

**EDIT 2/1/17**

Following the comment by ryguy72, I've updated the code to copy the tables from multiple selected word documents while the code runs in excel. The issue that I still have though is that I don't need ALL the tables in the files, I just need to be able to differentiate between Inputs and Outputs sections within the word doc as mentioned above and copy those specific tables. Ideally Inputs would be copied into one sheet, and outputs copied into another, with the sheets being kept between the word docs so it becomes a database of sorts. Is there a way to do this?

```
Sub GetWordDocContentsFromAllWordDocuments()
On Error Resume Next
  Dim oWord As Object
  Dim vFiles
  Dim iFile As Integer
  Dim iTable As Integer
  Dim tableNo As Integer
  Dim R As Range

  vFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc*),*.doc*",     Title:="Please select the files you want to copy from", MultiSelect:=True)
  If TypeName(vFiles) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub ' Cancelled
  Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  oWord.Visible = False
  Set R = Worksheets.Add.Range("A1")
  For iFile = LBound(vFiles) To UBound(vFiles)
    oWord.Documents.Open vFiles(iFile)
    tableNo = oWord.ActiveDocument.tables.Count
    For iTable = 1 To tableNo
        oWord.ActiveDocument.tables(iTable).Select
        oWord.Selection.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste R
        Set R = Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    Next
    oWord.ActiveDocument.Close False
  Next
  oWord.Quit
  Set oWord = Nothing
  ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will import tables in several Word docs...into Excel.  BTW, it runs in Excel...

```
Sub GetWordDocContentsFromAllWordDocuments()
On Error Resume Next
  Dim oWord As Object
  Dim vFiles
  Dim iFile As Integer
  Dim R As Range
  vFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc*),*.doc*", Title:="Please select the files you want to copy from", MultiSelect:=True)
  If TypeName(vFiles) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub ' Cancelled
  Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  oWord.Visible = True
  Set R = Worksheets.Add.Range("A1")
  For iFile = LBound(vFiles) To UBound(vFiles)
    oWord.Documents.Open vFiles(iFile)
    oWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
    oWord.Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste R
    Set R = Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    oWord.ActiveDocument.Close False
  Next
  oWord.Quit
  Set oWord = Nothing
  ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub



Sub GetWordDocContents()
  Dim oWord As Object
  Dim vFiles
  Dim iFile As Integer
  Dim R As Range
  vFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc*),*.doc*", Title:="Please select the files you want to copy from", MultiSelect:=True)
  If TypeName(vFiles) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub ' Cancelled
  Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  oWord.Visible = True
  Set R = Worksheets.Add.Range("A1")
  For iFile = LBound(vFiles) To UBound(vFiles)
    oWord.Documents.Open vFiles(iFile)
    oWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
    oWord.Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste R
    Set R = Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    oWord.ActiveDocument.Close False
  Next
  oWord.Quit
  Set oWord = Nothing
  ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, this definitely got my started with a better way to copy the tables, however I'm still stuck with only copying things between headings. The number of tables within Input and Output sections of the word docs can vary greatly.